# Jetpack Compose with Paging 3 making too many network requests

Tags: android

I am using Jetpack Compose with navigation component, Retrofit, and Paging 3. The problem I am having is that, when I navigate to the screen that has pagination, it makes 3 consecutive network requests, and when I navigate away to another screen, it makes a request again, and as a result of this, it's not caching. From performance standpoint, that is not good. I tried using `LauncdedEffect` in composable, but it's throwing a compilation error. What can I do to prevent this multiple requests?

**My viewModel:**

```
class CoursesViewModel(private val courseDataRepository: CourseDataRepository): ViewModel() {
    // ......
    fun getCourses(primaryCategory: String): Flow<PagingData<CourseData>> =
        courseDataRepository.getCourses(primaryCategory).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    // ......
}
```

**My Repository:**

```
interface CourseDataRepository {
    // ....
     fun getCourses(queryParam: String): Flow<PagingData<CourseData>>
    // ....
}


 class DefaultCourseDataRepository(private val retrofitService: EskoolApiService): CourseDataRepository { 
    // .....
      override fun getCourses(queryParam: String): Flow<PagingData<CourseData>> {
         return Pager(
             config = PagingConfig(pageSize = PAGE_SIZE),
             pagingSourceFactory = {
                 CourseDataSource(queryParam, retrofitService)
             }
         ).flow
     }
    // .....
}
```

**My DataSource:**

```
class CourseDataSource(
    private val queryIdentifier: String,
    private val apiService: EskoolApiService
): PagingSource<Int, CourseData>() {

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, CourseData>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, CourseData> {

        return try {
            val nextPage = params.key ?: 1
            val filters = mapOf("page" to nextPage, "page_size" to PAGE_SIZE)


            val data: Courses = if (queryIdentifier == defaultCoursesArg) {
                            apiService.getAllCourses(filters, null)
                        } else {
                            apiService.getAllCourses(filters, queryIdentifier)
                        }

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = data.courses,
                prevKey = if (nextPage == 1) null else nextPage - 1,
                nextKey = if (data.courses.isEmpty()) null else nextPage + 1
            )
        } catch (e: IOException) { // ************
            return LoadResult.Error(e)
            } catch (exception: HttpException) {
                return LoadResult.Error(exception)
            }
        }
}
```

**CoursesScreen**

```
@SuppressLint("MutableCollectionMutableState")
@Composable
fun CoursesScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    coursesViewModel: CoursesViewModel,
    coursesParam: String? = defaultCoursesArg,
    onClickCourseDetailsBySpan: (Int) -> Unit = {},
    onClickCourseDetailsByTitle: (Int) -> Unit = {},
) {

    val courseItems: LazyPagingItems<CourseData> =
        coursesViewModel.getCourses(coursesParam!!).collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(vertical = CARD_PADDING),
        color = colors.background
    ) {
        CourseCards(
            courses = courseItems,
            onClickCourseDetailsBySpan = onClickCourseDetailsBySpan,
            onClickCourseTitle = onClickCourseDetailsByTitle,
        )
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val coursesViewModel: CoursesViewModel = viewModel(factory = CoursesViewModel.Factory)
            // app content
            ESchoolApp(viewModel = coursesViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've written your method as:

```kotlin
fun getCourses(primaryCategory: String): Flow<PagingData<CourseData>> =
    courseDataRepository.getCourses(primaryCategory).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

That means that every time this method is called, you return a brand new Flow you've called `cachedIn` on - you aren't actually saving that Flow anywhere at your ViewModel layer, so every time your screen recomposes or when you return to that screen, you get a brand new Flow.

Instead, you need to:

1. Keep your `primaryCategory` state in your ViewModel. Expose a setter so your UI can set the category you are looking for.
2. Use that `primaryCategory` state as the input into your call to `courseDataRepository.getCourses`
3. Expose that final state to your UI using `cachedIn` to ensure that you are always returning a single Flow object that keeps cached data over a config change.

This would mean your `ViewModel` looks more like:

```kotlin
class CoursesViewModel(
    private val courseDataRepository: CourseDataRepository
): ViewModel() {
  // Keep your internal state as an observable MutableStateFlow
  // here defaulting to null
  private val primaryCategoryFlow = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

  // Allow your UI to change the primary category
  public fun setPrimaryCategory(primaryCategory: String) {
    primaryCategoryFlow.value = primaryCategory
  }

  // Transform each output of primaryCategoryFlow into a
  // new Flow from the courseDataRepository
  public val coursesFlow: Flow<PagingData<CourseData>> = primaryCategoryFlow
      .filterNotNull() // Skip our default value
      .distinctUntilLatest() // Don't return a new value if the category hasn't changed
      .flatMapLatest { primaryCategory ->
          courseDataRepository.getCourses(primaryCategory)
      }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

And your Composable changes to set the primary category and use the new, now actually cached Flow:

```kotlin
if (coursesParam != null) {
  coursesViewModel.setPrimaryCategory(coursesParam)
}
val courseItems: LazyPagingItems<CourseData> =
        coursesViewModel.coursesFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
```

You haven't included where you get your `coursesParam` from though - if it is an argument to one of the [Navigation Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) written screens of your app, then it would also be directly available to your ViewModel via a `SavedStateHandle` parameter, which would allow you to read it directly from there via `savedStateHandle.getStateFlow<String>("COURSES_PARAM")` (e.g., using whatever key you use when creating that argument) rather than needing a `setPrimaryCategory` method at all.

Comment: Thanks for the code explanation, @ianhanniballake. Yes, the `coursesParam` is a navigation argument.

Comment: Sounds like the `SavedStateHandle` way of getting that would certainly be cleaner than having to parse it in your composable and pass it to the ViewModel then!

Comment: Yes, I am following that route, but trying to figure out how to achieve that. I am somehow a newbie in this. Thanks for the help @ianhanniballake.

Comment: I still got infinite netw request, my code in viewmodel and repository has followed as mention above. So, can you share me in Screen?